# My extension method isn't registering (Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'PageLinks' and ...)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods

I'm following Pro ASP.Net MVC2 book and literally 90% of everything is new to me. I feel like a kid in a candy store! :)

Unit testing, dependency injection, and other things are really new and very foreign to the typical CRUD applications I create.

Now I'm having trouble with a test the book asks us to design.

```
[Test]
        public void Can_Generate_Links_To_Other_Pages()
        {
            // Arrange: We're going to extend the HtmlHelper class.
            // It doesn't matter if the variable we use is null.
            HtmlHelper html = null;

            // Arrange: The helper should take a PagingInfo instance (that's
            // a class we haven't yet defined) and a lambda to specify the URLs
            PagingInfo pagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = 2,
                TotalItems = 28,
                ItemsPerPage = 10
            };
            
            Func<int, string> pageUrl = i => "Page" + i;

            // Act
            MvcHtmlString result = html.PageLinks(pagingInfo, pageUrl);

            // Assert: Here's how it should format the links
            result.ToString().ShouldEqual(@"<a href=""Page1"">1</a>
                                            <a class=""selected"" href=""Page2"">2</a>
                                            <a href=""Page3"">3</a>");
        }
```

My html variable is a HtmlHelper variable. It seems that the extension method PageLinks() isn't correctly registered.

Where would I check for this?

### Edit

Apparently this is where I registered the extension method. Although it doesn't seem to extend anything. At least IntelliSense doesn't show it when I type it in the above code.

```
public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());         
        }
    }
```

Also, how can I set up Visual Studio so it just copies plain text without its ridiculous indentation?

### Edit 2

Woops! Forgot to type in the error:

> Error 1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
> does not contain a definition for
> 'PageLinks' and no extension method
> 'PageLinks' accepting a first argument
> of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
> could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   C:\Users\Sergio\documents\visual
> studio
> 2010\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.UnitTests\DisplayingPageLinks.cs    35  41  SportsStore.UnitTests

Comment: You left out the part where you explain what happens, do you get a compiler error? The wrong results?

Comment: What I do is un-indent the code to the lowest level, copy and paste it, then undo my changes.

Comment: The problem should be fixed by adding a `using` statement to the file that contains the test, pointing at the namespace your `PagingHelpers`-class is. For instance, if `PagingHelpers` is put in namespace `test123`, you should add `using test123;` to the top of the file containing your test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use an extension method, you need to include the namespace in which the extension method class resides. You also need to ensure the extension method class is static and accessible to consuming code (e.g. can't be internal if it's in another assembly). Finally, be sure not to forget the `this` keyword on the type you're extending. If all those things are in place, you shouldn't see a problem.

Comment: Also, if you're writing the extension method yourself, don't forget the `this` parameter keyword.

Comment: You're right, I had to add the using namespace so it would register.

Comment: @Sergio feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

You can add the namespace to all your pages in the web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
 <pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
    <add namespace="YourNameSpace.HtmlHelpers"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
MvcHtmlString result = PagingHelpers.PageLinks(myHelper, pagingInfo, pageUrlDelegate);
```

instead of

```
MvcHtmlString result = myHelper.PageLinks(pagingInfo, pageUrlDelegate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your List.cshtml above the code this line

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `this HtmlHelper html,` from parameters of PageLinks method code in PagingHelpers class, and replace HtmlHelper with PagingHelpers 
like this 
`MvcHtmlString result = PagingHelpers.PageLinks(pagingInfo, pageUrl);`

`HtmlHelper` is not used in your example.